# Meaning of すい歴史

Tags: meaning

I wonder, what mean word すい歴史? (I just recognized it that way)

[image: すい歴史]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That says 「古{ふる}い歴史{れきし}」= "old history", not 「すい歴史」.

「すい歴史」 makes no sense.